# Q_ASSERT release build semantics

Tags: c++, qt, assertions

I can't find a clear statement on the semantics of Q_ASSERT under release builds. If there is no assertion checking, then is the asserted expression evaluated at all?

Consider the following code

```
Q_ASSERT(do_something_report_false_if_failed());
```

Will `do_something_report_false_if_failed()` run under all potential Qt build configurations? Would it be safer (even though a bit more verbose and less readable) to do this instead:

```
bool is_ok = do_something_report_false_if_failed();
Q_ASSERT(is_ok)
```

The latter approach has the downside that ASSERT failures are less verbose, but perhaps it  shows more clearly that the statement is executed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The expression inside the `Q_ASSERT` will **not** be evaluated in non-debug build configurations.

Consider the source code below from the [Qt repo](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/global/qglobal.h?h=5.4).

```
#if !defined(Q_ASSERT)
#  ifndef QT_NO_DEBUG
#    define Q_ASSERT(cond) ((!(cond)) ? qt_assert(#cond,__FILE__,__LINE__) : qt_noop())
#  else
#    define Q_ASSERT(cond) qt_noop()    
#  endif    
#endif
```

If `QT_NO_DEBUG` is defined, then the entire `Q_ASSERT` statement is replaced with a `qt_noop()`, thereby removing any expression that it previously contained.

Never rely on any side effects created by an expression inside a `Q_ASSERT` statement. Technically it is still possible to ensure that `QT_NO_DEBUG` is not defined in a specific build configuration, but this is not a Good Idea™.

Comment: That's exactly the same situation as with regular `assert` and `NDEBUG` macro.

Answer (score 16):

This seems to be different in [Qt5.5](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/global/qglobal.h?h=5.5) (but not earlier - see [Qt5.4](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/global/qglobal.h?h=5.4)):

```
#if !defined(Q_ASSERT)
#  if defined(QT_NO_DEBUG) && !defined(QT_FORCE_ASSERTS)
#    define Q_ASSERT(cond) do { } while ((false) && (cond))
#  else
#    define Q_ASSERT(cond) ((!(cond)) ? qt_assert(#cond,__FILE__,__LINE__) : qt_noop())
#  endif
#endif
```

I'm now getting lots of "​warning C4127: conditional expression is constant" in Visual Studio 2013.

Update:
[Qt5.5 release notes](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/dist/changes-5.5.0) say:

> Q_ASSERT will now expand the condition even in release mode when
>   asserts are disabled, albeit in an unreachable code path. This
>   solves compiler warnings about variables and functions that were
>   unused in release mode because they were only used in assertions.
>   Unfortunately, codebases that hid those functions and variables
>   via #ifndef will need to remove the conditionals to compile with Qt 5.5.

Comment: Redefining Q_ASSERT and Q_ASSERT_X back to noop helps

Comment: This is the change in gerrit: https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/94460/3

Comment: I am having the same problem. Is this fixed in Qt versions > 5.5?